# How to import music into Android library

Tags: android

I would like to know how can I import songs from a web service into
Android library without having to download the file into sdcard.
I have all the data from the web service but I do not know how to
integrate the tracks into Android database. My idea is not to have to
download the files, but playing them on streaming using the music
player.
Do I need to download the tracks to the sd card and then Android does
all the stuff?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Do I need to download the tracks to
>   the sd card and then Android does all
>   the stuff?

Yes. The "Android library" (a.k.a., `MediaStore`) is for music, images, and videos that are locally stored on the device. If you want to do streaming media, that is fine, but that has nothing to do with `MediaStore`, AFAIK.

Comment: I think you are right, because I have been trying to do that and it does not work. MediaStore only works with local files. Anyway, don´t you think that it could be at least reasonable the possibility of adding files to MediaStore from web sites?. This way you could add tracks to your music library and they could be played in streaming.